# Convert first character to capital along with special character separator

Tags: bash

I would like to convert first character to capital and character coming after dash(-) needs to be converted to capital using bash.

I can split individual elements using - ,

```
echo "string" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
```

and join all but that doesn't seem effect. Is there any easy way to take care of this using single line?

## Input string:

```
JASON-CONRAD-983636
```

## Expected string:

```
Jason-Conrad-983636
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/\L&/;s/\b./\u&/g' file
```

Lowercase everything. Uppercase first characters of words.

Alternative:

```
sed -E 's/\b(.)((\B.)*)/\u\1\L\2/g' file
```

Comment: Superb solution!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Python for this:

```
python3 -c 'import sys; print("-".join(s.capitalize() for s in sys.stdin.read().split("-")))'
```

Usage:

```
capitalize() {
  python3 -c 'import sys; print("-".join(s.capitalize() for s in sys.stdin.read().split("-")))'
}

echo JASON-CONRAD-983636 | capitalize
```

Output:

```
Jason-Conrad-983636
```

Comment: Thanks Alfe for the answer, used bash way.

Comment: Used `awk` instead, you mean ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In pure `bash` (v4+) without any third party utils

```
str=JASON-CONRAD-983636
IFS=- read -ra raw <<<"$str"

final=()
for str in "${raw[@]}"; do 
    first=${str:0:1}
    rest=${str:1}
    final+=( "${first^^}${rest,,}" )
done
```

and print the result

```
( IFS=- ; printf '%s\n' "${final[*]}" ; )
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(in case you are ok with `awk`).

```
var="JASON-CONRAD-983636"
echo "$var" | awk -F'-' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=substr($i,1,1) tolower(substr($i,2))}} 1' OFS="-"
```

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, no problem :) changed it now accordingly, kindly check once?

Comment: @JiteshSojitra: If you are asking to do this in `bash`, use constructs in `bash` and not third party utils like `awk`. Edit the question if you want to do this in other tools also

Answer (score 1):

Although the party is mostly over, please let me join with a `perl` solution:

```
perl -pe 's/(^|-)([^-]+)/$1 . ucfirst lc $2/ge' <<<"JASON-CONRAD-983636"
```

It may be cunning to use the `ucfirst` function :)